# Forward Fill NA values with discount rate conditional on sign of previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to forward fill `NaN` values in a `DataFrame` with a discount rate conditional on the sign of the previous value. So far, I was able to include a discount rate in the forward fill of the `NaN` values. Here would be a simple example dataset `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Column1':[1.255, 'NaN', 3.558, 'NaN'], 
                    'Column2':[5, 6, 7, 8], 
                    'Column3':[-9, -10, 'NaN', 'NaN'], 
                    'Column4':[13, 15, 'NaN', 'NaN']
                    })
df1 = df1.replace('NaN',np.nan)

df1: 
    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0   1.255   5       -9.0    13.0
1   NaN     6       -10.0   15.0
2   3.558   7       NaN     NaN
3   NaN     8       NaN     NaN
```

I included a discount rate of 0.9 for the forward fill.

```
rate = 0.9
groups = df1.notna().cumsum()
exp = df1.apply(lambda col: col.isna().groupby(groups[col.name]).cumsum())
df2 = df1.ffill().mul(rate ** exp)

df2:

    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0   1.2550  5.0     -9.0    13.00
1   1.1295  6.0     -10.0   15.00
2   3.5580  7.0     -9.0    13.50
3   3.2022  8.0     -8.1    12.15
```

How would I need to adjust the code to have a discount rate of 0.9 for positive numbers (as in the example) but a discount rate of 0.7 for negative numbers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mask on the negative and positive values, something like this should work:

```
groups = df1.notna().cumsum()
exp = df1.apply(lambda col: col.isna().groupby(groups[col.name]).cumsum())
df2 = df1.ffill()
rate_p = 0.9
rate_n = 0.7
mask_p = df2 > 0
mask_n = df2 < 0
df2 *= (rate_p ** exp) * mask_p + (rate_n ** exp) * mask_n
```